# Скачивание и загрузка с яндекс, гоогле диска а также с облака майла с помощью Python

Tags: python

Как реализовать выгрузку файлов из Mail.ru, Google или из Яндек дисков при помощи Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У каждого облачного хранилища практически всегда есть SDK под разные языки
первая же ссылка при поиске "gdrive sdk python": 
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python

Comment: я новечек  в программировании ... и первым языком для программирования выбрал Python, пока еще туго соображаю в этом ... это как я понял надо скачать библиотеку , затем ее установить и затем импортировать а уж потом пытаться что-то сделать, правильно ?